# Recursion - Amount of files in selected folder between certain file size

Tags: java, recursion

Learning recursion and I'm not sure why this isn't working. I need it to give me the total amount of files that are between 10000 bytes to 25000 bytes in a folder that I choose. There should be 3 files that should be returned but it's not incrementing.

Here's what I got:

```
    public static int betweenFileSize(File f) {
    if (f.isFile()) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        int amountOfFiles = 0;

        for (File file : f.listFiles()) {
            if (file.isHidden() == false) {

                if (file.length() >= 10000 && file.length() <= 25000) {
                    amountOfFiles += betweenFileSize(file);
                }
            }
        }
        return amountOfFiles;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are making a recursive call to `betweenFileSize` for files that are in the size range you are looking for. This makes no sense.

You should only call that method recursively for files that are directories. For files that satisfy your size criteria, simply add 1 to the count.

```
public static int betweenFileSize(File f) {
    if (f.isFile()) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        int amountOfFiles = 0;

        for (File file : f.listFiles()) {
            if (file.isHidden() == false) {

                if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    amountOfFiles += betweenFileSize(file);
                } else if (file.length() >= 10000 && file.length() <= 25000) {
                    amountOfFiles++;
                }
            }
        }
        return amountOfFiles;
    }
}
```